# Как создать форму с данными?

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать форму в которой уже будут данные и с правой стороны будет кнопка для копирования данных с этой формы? Что то похожее как на скриншоте!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, как то так, но вариаций огромное множество!

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="Что то" name="your_input_name">
    <button type="button" onclick="copyInput('your_input_name')">Скопировать</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.copyInput = (name) => {
        document.querySelector('input[name=' + name + ']').select();
        try {
            document.execCommand('copy');
            console.log('Скопировано!');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Копирование не удалось');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Этот вариант подходит не только для bootstrap. Надеюсь со стилями справитесь самостоятельно!

Comment: Копирование не происходит, и сообщений не получаю

Comment: Забыл .select() =) подправил!

Comment: Спасибо большое